# is the WebProvisioned event fired when using restore-spsite?

Tags: event-handlers

Can somebody confirm that the WebProvisioned event is not fired when using restore-spsite?

I have made some tests and it looks like it's not the case but I would like to make sure.

If it's not the case, does somebody have an alternative of firing some code after restoring the spsite ?

Answer (score 1):

At a guess, I'd say no, as WebProvisioned is after a website is provisioned from a template, `Restore-SPSite` is essentially a database restore, no provisioning happens.

As it's a Powershell command, you can probably do what you need to do in PowerShell after the `Restore-SPSite` call.